# Printed python JSON back into python

Tags: python, json

So, I had someone send me a JSON dump of some data, but they obviously did it lazily (by printing) in python so that the (simplified) data is:

```
{u'x': u'somevalue', u'y': u'someothervalue'}
```

instead of valid JSON:

```
{"x": "somevalue", "y": "someothervalue"}
```

Since it's not valid JSON, json.loads() naturally fails to parse it.

Does Python include any modules to parse its own output like this?  I actually think parsing it myself might be faster than trying to explain to this guy what he did wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to get away with the following:

```
>>> s = "{u'x': u'somevalue', u'y': u'someothervalue'}"
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(s)
{u'y': u'someothervalue', u'x': u'somevalue'}
```

Comment: Right.  There is also the original, unsafe, built-in `eval()` as well.  But don't use `eval()`, use `ast.literal_eval()`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval

Answer (score 1):

The [demjson](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/) python module allows for strict and non-strict operation.  Here's a list of some of the allowances in non-strict mode:

> The following are permitted when processing in NON-STRICT mode:
>
> ```
> * Unicode format control characters are allowed anywhere in the input.
> * All Unicode line terminator characters are recognized.
> * All Unicode white space characters are recognized.
> * The 'undefined' keyword is recognized.
> * Hexadecimal number literals are recognized (e.g., 0xA6, 0177).
> * String literals may use either single or double quote marks.
> * Strings may contain \x (hexadecimal) escape sequences, as well as the
>   \v and \0 escape sequences.
> * Lists may have omitted (elided) elements, e.g., [,,,,,], with
>   missing elements interpreted as 'undefined' values.
> * Object properties (dictionary keys) can be of any of the
>   types: string literals, numbers, or identifiers (the later of
>   which are treated as if they are string literals)---as permitted
>   by ECMAScript.  JSON only permits strings literals as keys.
> ```

Comment: This was going to be an additional suggestion to my answer, but I couldn't get it to work - any idea if there's any argument that should be used to meet the OP's requirement?

Comment: @Jon Clements When you initialize the JSON class you can pass in `strict=False` which enables the list of allowances I posted above.  From reading Josh's example, it looks like they should allow the content to be parsed.  However, for the specific use-case listed by Josh, I think your answer is a much better solution anyway :)